# raspberry pi 4 + bluez の構成から gatt のデータを受信できない

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

raspberry pi 4 2台(raspberry0、raspberry1)で、7/24現在で以下の方法でrasbianとbluezを両RPiにInstallしています。

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt purge --auto-remove wolfram*
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
sudo rpi-update
sudo apt-get install -y pi-bluetooth raspberrypi-sys-mods
sudo apt-get install bluetooth
sudo apt install -y libusb-dev libdbus-1-dev libglib2.0-dev libudev-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev libbluetooth-dev
sudo apt install bluez
sudo usermod -aG bluetooth pi
newgrp bluetooth
sudo reboot
```

起動後、`service` コマンドでbluetoothのserviceを見ると正常に見えます。

```sh
$ service bluetooth status
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-07-24 06:28:48 BST; 2min 33s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 580 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 3874)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─580 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jul 24 06:28:48 raspberry0 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jul 24 06:28:48 raspberry0 bluetoothd[580]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Jul 24 06:28:48 raspberry0 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jul 24 06:28:48 raspberry0 bluetoothd[580]: Starting SDP server
Jul 24 06:28:48 raspberry0 bluetoothd[580]: Bluetooth management interface 1.18 initialized
Jul 24 06:28:48 raspberry0 bluetoothd[580]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Jul 24 06:28:48 raspberry0 bluetoothd[580]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Jul 24 06:28:49 raspberry0 bluetoothd[580]: Failed to set privacy: Rejected (0x0b)
Jul 24 06:31:12 raspberry0 bluetoothd[580]: No cache for DC:A6:32:97:17:7E
```

また、hci0を見るとこちらも正常起動しているように見えます。

```sh
$ hciconfig -a
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
        BD Address: DC:A6:32:7A:9C:3A  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
        UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN
        RX bytes:1811 acl:3 sco:0 events:118 errors:0
        TX bytes:2731 acl:4 sco:0 commands:108 errors:0
        Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3
        Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
        Name: 'raspberry0'
        Class: 0x000fdc
        Service Classes: Unspecified
        Device Class: Invalid Device Class!
        HCI Version: 5.0 (0x9)  Revision: 0x156
        LMP Version: 5.0 (0x9)  Subversion: 0x6119
        Manufacturer: Cypress Semiconductor Corporation (305)
```

Adverise送出のため、raspberry0で以下を実行。
(なぜかbluez-5.50に添付のexample-advertisementはErrorで起動できません)

```sh
sudo hciconfig hci0 leadv 0
```

その後、raspberry1でgatttoolを起動して、raspberry0のGATTを見ると正常にGATTが見られます。

```sh
$ sudo gatttool -b DC:A6:32:7A:9C:3A -I
[DC:A6:32:7A:9C:3A][LE]> connect
Attempting to connect to DC:A6:32:7A:9C:3A
Connection successful
Indication   handle = 0x0008 value: 26 00 41 00
[DC:A6:32:7A:9C:3A][LE]> primary
attr handle: 0x0001, end grp handle: 0x0005 uuid: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x0006, end grp handle: 0x0009 uuid: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

その後、raspberry0でbluea-5.50のexample-gatt-serverを起動すると、raspberry1側ではexample-gatt-serverの設定が正常に有効に見えます。

```
Indication   handle = 0x0008 value: 42 00 49 00
Indication   handle = 0x0008 value: 4a 00 4d 00
Indication   handle = 0x0008 value: 4e 00 5d 00
[DC:A6:32:7A:9C:3A][LE]> primary
attr handle: 0x0001, end grp handle: 0x0005 uuid: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x0006, end grp handle: 0x0009 uuid: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x0042, end grp handle: 0x0049 uuid: 0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x004a, end grp handle: 0x004d uuid: 0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x004e, end grp handle: 0x005d uuid: 12345678-1234-5678-1234-56789abcdef0
[DC:A6:32:7A:9C:3A][LE]>
```

しかし、この状態でAndrod端末で、Nordic社製nRF Connectでraspberry0を見てもDevice Informationの`0000180a-...`しか見ることができません。

```
00001800-...
00001801-...
```

raspberry1でgatttoolの結果からgattには正しく設定されているにも関わらず、他のToolで見えないことから、bluezが正しくgattを公開していないように見えるのですが、どなたか原因と対策方法は判るでしょうか？

Comment: `gatttool` は廃止になってるようです。内部の DBus APIが変更になった模様。参考: https://wiki.archlinux.jp/index.php/Bluetooth https://qiita.com/ohisama@github/items/cff60355d4dfcf96c2ac
あと他に, `apt-get` と `apt` が混在してるけど, 複数ヶ所から記事参照したのでしょうか？
特に, `rpi-update` は危険なので無闇に入れるべきではないです https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/computers/os.html#rpi-update

Comment: (少し付け加えると) DBus APIが違うはずなので, 共存できてるようだけど共有はムリ。btmgmt などのツールは見つかるけど btgatt-client見当たらなさそうなので, 待つか作るか？